# Removing .html causes a link to a folder

Tags: .htaccess

In my .htaccess file I've added the following code;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

This removes all the .html perfectly from my pages, but there is a problem that directs one page to a folder.

Originally I had, `www.domain.com/work.html` and `www.domain.com/work/client.html` but now when you go to `www.domain.com/work` it tries to go to the folder, `www.domain.com/work/`

Does someone know how to fix this so that domain/work goes to what was domain/work.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because mod_dir sees that `/work` points to a physical folder and since it's missing a trailing slash, it automatically redirects the browser to `/work/`. The `DirectorySlash` directive does this and it's turned on by default (for **very good reasons**, as there's a information disclosure security concern that lets people view the contents of your directory even with an index file when it's turned off). This redirect happens *before* mod_rewrite even gets applied, so your rule isn't even being considered.

If you really want your site setup this way, you'll have to turn off directory slash, and kind of do what directory slash does for you:

```
Options -Multiviews
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

# append the html:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.html [L]

# now handle the directory redirects:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

Comment: I've just tried this and it now does display domain.com/work as the html page, but domain.com/work/client gives a 404.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I can now, 1. Go to bed happy 2.Launch my new site tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: Hello, I've ran into a small problem. I've got a wordpress blog as domain.com/blog and it's not working.

Comment: Ok, I can add domain.com/blog/ to my pages and that works. I guess I can set up a redirect for domain.com/blog if anyone types that in?

Comment: @OliverB Yeah, you can add this right below `RewriteEngine On`: `RewriteRule ^blog$ /blog/ [L,R=301]`